# Why list comprehension can affect the value of an outer variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

If you run this code with Python 2.7,

```
i = 5
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [i*i for i in x if i % 2 == 0]
```

The value of `i` is changed to 4. But how?

Comment: python 3 or python 2?

Comment: The value is equal to 5 with python 3.

Comment: Use another variable name in your loop if you use python 2.

Comment: I can use another variable of course, but I was just asking the reason why it can cause this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're using Python 2.7, which leaks the variables defined in the comprehension. On the last iteration the `i` in the loop is equal to 4, and the name `i` from the comprehensionthen shadows the global name once control leaves the comprehension.

Python 3 doesn't do that anymore, though, so you should update.

Answer (score 2):

That's a Python 2 specific limitation. Variables inside list comprehension have their own scope in Python 3:

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar 11 2019, 11:54:40) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> i = 5
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> y = [i*i for i in x if i == 2]
>>> i
5
```